# Controlling Foreign Key Name in EF Reverse POCO Generator

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I am using Simon Hughes' Reverse POCO Generator to generate my domain entities.

I have a `ProcedureLogbook` table which *Foreign Keys* back to the `Procedure` table. Nothing special. Just a straight reference back to a Pk - m:1. I also have a 2nd relationship with the `Procedure` table. That 2nd relationship is causing me no grief and is naming the Navigation property as expected i.e. ReportingProcedure (FK is called `FK_ProcedureLogbookType_ReportingProcedure`).

For the other relationship (the main one), the POCO Generator creates a navigation Property in the `ProcedureLogbook` class called `Procedure_ProcedureId`, instead of just `Procedure`. The FK is called `FK_ProcedureLogbookType_Procedure`.

Code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parent Procedure pointed by [ProcedureLogbookType].([ProcedureId]) (FK_ProcedureLogbookType_Procedure)
/// </summary>
public virtual Procedure Procedure1 { get; set; } // FK_ProcedureLogbookType_Procedure

/// <summary>
/// Parent Procedure pointed by [ProcedureLogbookType].([ReportingProcedureId]) (FK_ProcedureLogbookType_ReportingProcedure)
/// </summary>
public virtual Procedure ReportingProcedure { get; set; } // FK_ProcedureLogbookType_ReportingProcedure
```

I attempted to force its hand by putting the following code in the `ForeignKeyNames` closure:

```
if (foreignKey.ConstraintName.Equals("FK_ProcedureLogbookType_Procedure"))
{
    if (foreignKey.FkTableName.Equals("ProcedureLogbookType"))
    {
        return "Procedure";
    }
}
```

That gave me a Nav Property called `Procedure1`.
Any idea what the problem is? I'd like to be able to use code like:

```
procedureLogbook.Procedure == etc
```

Note: I've also tried the following code, as I noticed the NavigationProperty on the other end of the relationship was getting a "1" suffixed to it as well:

```
if (foreignKey.ConstraintName == "FK_ProcedureLogbookType_Procedure")
{
    if(relationship == Relationship.OneToMany)
        return "ProcedureLogbookTypes";
    return "Procedure";
}
```

Still no result. How do I get rid of the "1" suffix?

In addition to that, in my Procedure entity, it is not getting the pluralization correct for one of the navigation properties (the `ReportingProcedure` one referenced above). It is creating the following:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProcedureLogbookType> ReportingProcedure { get; set; }
```

Being a collection, it should be plural.

(Cross posted in Pluralsight Discussion forum for the course Code-first Entity Framework with Legacy Databases)

Comment: If you use the latest version of the generator do you still get the same problem?

Comment: @SimonHughes Let me try that. I used 2.33. Current is 2.36. I'll have to customize the files again etc. Note to self - find way to keep track of changes of the customizations. Will come back with result in a day or so. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonHughes The update to 2.36 did not go well. The template runs, but it is creating duplicate properties in my entites. So the project is not building anymore. And it is not the properties which are the subject of this question. Just other foreign keys in entities. Any idea why it would create properties with the same type and name?

Comment: It should definitely not be creating duplicate properties. Could you email me the Sql DDL for the related tables and I shall take a look. simon [at] hicrest .net

Comment: @SimonHughes Thanks Simon. I'll turn that around as quickly as possible. This project is potentially a death march, so it may take a day or 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the EF.Reverse.POCO.Core.ttinclude you can update the logic for Attempt 5 (Line 3622 in v2.36.1) so it won't add the suffix on the first iteration of the loop

```
// Attempt 5
        for (int n = 0; n < 99; ++n)
        {
            col = Settings.ForeignKeyName(tableNameHumanCase, foreignKey, fkName, relationship, 5);

            if (n > 0)
            {
                col += n;
            }

            if (ReverseNavigationUniquePropName.Contains(col))
                continue;

            if(addReverseNavigationUniquePropName)
            {
                ReverseNavigationUniquePropName.Add(col);
            }

            return col;
        }
```